# Visual studio warning C6308 exist in shrinking dynamic array

Tags: c, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

**Why I am getting a warning when shrinking arrays?

There is no any way of losing the pointer value.**

Warning C6308   'realloc' might return null pointer: assigning null pointer to 'arr_all_guests', which is passed as an argument to 'realloc', will cause the original memory block to be leaked.

`arr_all_guests = (char**)realloc(arr_all_guests,--(*guest_counter) * sizeof(char*));`

Comment: It's exactly as the message says, `realloc` may return a null pointer. You have no checks for that

Comment: The call to `realloc` *could* potentially fail (even though you're shrinking the block). The compiler is doing its duty by warning you about that.

Comment: If `*guest_counter == 0`, beforehand, this is certainly not shrinking the allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that as it is written the function `realloc` can return a null pointer. In this case an access to all the early allocated memory will be lost

```
arr_all_guests = (char**)realloc(arr_all_guests,--(*guest_counter) * sizeof(char*));
```

because the original pointer `arr_all_guests` will be reassigned with a null pointer.

You need to use a temporary pointer as for example

```
char **tmp = realloc(arr_all_guests, ( *guest_counter - 1 ) * sizeof(char*)); 
if ( tmp != NULL ) 
{
    arr_all_guests = tmp;
    --*guest_counter;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But I think I did not explain myself clearly. When making smaller dynamic arrays, there is no chance of losing data because of the mechanism of the function that releases the cells as I requested and returns a pointer to exactly the same place to which the pointer pointed. The NULL return can only occur in one case (in some versions of C): Reducing the array to size 0.

Comment: @Moshe The function realloc works the following way. At first it tries to allocate a new extent of memory.  It is not necessary that the function will try to reallocate (resize) the previously allocated extent of memory. If the allocation of a new extent was successful the function copies elements from the old extent to the new one and then frees the old extent of memory. Otherwise the function returns a null pointer.